# Legend Duplication

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I have the following implementation and it is functional.

I wonder how I could able to fix duplicate of legend in my current implementation. Please watch `fname="NY"`

[image]

```
for (var i=0;i<e.series.data.length;i++){
  if (e.series.data[i].valueColor != "" && e.series.data[i].fname != "") {
    color = e.series.data[i].valueColor,
    legendName=e.series.data[i].fname
  }
}
```

### **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/1ost124j/3/)**

Comment: Keep a history of labels you have added and check to see if that label has already been added.

Comment: Click the JSHint button on the fiddle to see a number of coding errors.

Comment: if you use the same series number for similar fnames, your problem would go away: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/1ost124j/17/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By logging the data that you're charting, you can see that the code is called for 6 items. If you add `category` to the label, you can see that legends are being created for items from Men and Women:

[image: example]

You should debug the data structure that is actually generating labels.

http://jsfiddle.net/xmufd8t0/1/ shows this inside the console:
[image: data]

There appears to be an issue with how you use this loop: you always take the final element in `e.series.data`. If you want the first non-empty `fname`, you should have a `break;` after setting `legendName`. Otherwise it takes the last item in the array that is non-empty.

Anyway - to answer your question, you need to dedupe as @honerlawd mentioned in his comment. Here's the deduplication fix:

```
// outside your function, where you have `debugger`
var dedupes = {};

....

// skip labels that have already been added
if (dedupes.hasOwnProperty(legendName)) {
    return;
}
dedupes[legendName] = 1;
```

Comment: Hi Ben, your images are broken. could u please fix and provide fiddle?

Comment: Sure, Andrea. Sorry about that. I've also included the deduplication in the fiddle.